# Get Total Value of Bill Number - Tableau calculated field

Tags: tableau-api, calculated-field

My CSV contains the below data.

[image]

I am using a calculated field that is returning 40.

```
IF CONTAINS([Description],'Veg')
THEN [Amount]
END
```

But I want to total the sum amount of the bill numbers where any bill number matches these criteria -  **Description** contains **Veg**.

here, bill number 2 contains veg in 1 row (10), so I want to get the total amount of that full bill number (20).

My expected output is 50.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not that difficult.  Proceed like this-

create your desired amount field by this calculation-

```
IF { FIXED [Bill]: MAX(INT(CONTAINS([Description], 'veg')))}>0
THEN [Amount] ELSE 0 END
```

Screenshot

[image]

[image]